# Nmap7.5:how to add scripts into its path except /usr/share/nmap/scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nmap

I once installed nmap7.1 on my Ubuntu and added some nse scripts into its path `/usr/share/nmap/scripts`but when I remove nmap7.1 and install nmap7.5 with the official source and compiled myself ,I find there is a few nse scripts which are those I once added and the `nmap` command can not using these scripts.But my python programs need these nse scripts ,so my question is where should these nse scripts added to  OR which command could add this nse scripts into Nmap Path and working properly.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem:this is my cocument structure:

```
scan_s/nse/modicon-info.nse
      /namp.py
```

this my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from libnmap.process import NmapProcess
from time import sleep
try:
  import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 
except ImportError: 
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
import sys 

nmap_proc = NmapProcess(targets="45.76.197.202", options="--script nse/s7-info.nse -p 102")
nmap_proc.run_background()
while nmap_proc.is_running():
    sleep(2)    
xml = nmap_proc.stdout
print xml
xmlfiled = open('testxml.xml','w')
xmlfiled.write(xml)
xmlfiled.close()
try:
    tree = ET.parse('testxml.xml')
    root =  tree.getroot()
    test = root.find('host').find('ports').find('port').find('script')
    test_dic = dict(test.attrib)
    s = test_dic['output']
except:
    s = 'unknown'
print s
```

hope it can help you :)